# Can't catch 404 exception when there is no path mapping for the specified URI

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, http-status-code-404

say this is my URI for messages collection in my REST API using jersey "http://localhost:8080/messengerApp/webapi/messages" it returns all messages as json

```
[{"message": "helo navaratnam","id": 3,"author": "xyz"},
 {"message": "hi ilango","id": 4,"author": "xyza"}
]
```

incase if I typed uri like this "http://localhost:8080/messengerApp/webapi/mess" it is producing an html response like below

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Errorbody {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server ErrorType Status ReportDescription The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.Apache Tomcat/9.0.34
```

i just want to notify developer he has send a wrong URI using a json response back similar to below

```
{
    "errorCode": "404",
    "documentation": "something wrong please check your request",
    "errorMessage": "requested resource not available"
}
```

this is my generic exception mapper

```
package com.jatha.messengerapp.exception;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import com.jatha.messengerapp.model.ErrorMessage;

@Provider
public class GenericExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Throwable ex) {
//just to check the exception is reaching this mapper
        System.out.println("GenericExceptionMapper");

        ErrorMessage er = new ErrorMessage(ex.getMessage(),"404","something wrong please check your request");
        return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND)
                .entity(er)
                .build();
    }
    

}
```

pretty much most exceptions are captured here and JSON is generated. when the URI is wrong as mentioned above the exception is reaching this mapper but the html page is generated instead of json.

the solutions just to handle this in the generic exception handler or some separate handler/mapper to capture this also much appreciated. i don't want to return any html pages. just want to return JSON to the developer.
**I'm using Apache Tomcat/9.0.34 , jersey 1.19.4**

Comment: If you're page does not exist it should return error 404 and I don't understand that 550 response code. Anyway to personalize a message you need to modify `.htaccess` file adding the line: `ErrorDocument 404 /not-found.php` (or 500 in your case) and then let your php script (or whatever server side language you're using) write your json error message

Comment: @virgula   Since jersey reached the base URI  "/webapi/*" it is looking for the '@path' to map a recourse. since no resource get mapped and that exception is not handled any where, server is showing a default internal server error page with 500. before the exception is propagated to server i just want to handle it and send a json response similar to above. i want it to be handled in a generic exception mapper like above or in a specific mapper.